# Is it possible to crop an online image using react-image-crop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-image-crop

I know that it is possible to crop an image that is locally stored in your computer using the npm package [react-image-crop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop).
But, is it possible to get an already uploaded/online image through its url and then crop it using the same package?

Answer (score 0):

The [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop#example) in the component's readme shows how to use it with an `<img/>`, so yes, I'd reckon it is possible to use the visual crop component with any image you can get an `src` to.

```
function CropDemo({ src }) {
  const [crop, setCrop] = useState<Crop>()
  return (
    <ReactCrop crop={crop} onChange={c => setCrop(c)}>
      <img src={src} />
    </ReactCrop>
  )
}
```

Actually cropping a remote image may not be possible entirely in the browser (using the Canvas API) thanks to cross-origin issues, but that's not what the component does, anyway.

Comment: It means that if an image is online (not selected from local computer) we cannot get the cropped image, right? We can definitely crop the image but cannot get it to use in our code

Comment: Well, `react-image-crop` doesn't _do_ that in the first place...

Comment: Oh okay, I got it.. I just had to add `crossOrigin="anonymous"` in the img tag in order to get the cropped image and convert it to blob.